# Can't run d3js to a website (jupyter notebook)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, jupyter-notebook

I don't really know much about html, d3js or javascript but according to some course in Udacity I could load d3js to any website inputting this code in the web developer console:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Looks pretty straightforward, and it has worked with every page I've tried except my jupyter notebook. The script gets appended in the `<head>` tag but it has really low opacity and when I try to run some d3js code it doesn't work (running `d3.select("p");` gives `ReferenceError: d3 is not defined`). Is there any other workaround?

Comment: You state that you "can't load d3js" but then you say "the script gets appended" - so it *can* load. "[...] it has really low opacity" -> this is probably your real question, but to answer it we need more relevant details.

Comment: @le_m You're right, wrote it really badly, just editted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you need to make d3 global.  What I do in a cell is this.  Jupyter already has require loaded.

```
%%javascript
require.config({
    paths: {
        d3: "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min"
     }
});

require(["d3"], function(d3) {
    window.d3 = d3;
});
```

Comment: It worked, I wanted to run d3 through the web browser console and not through a cell (so I can use greasemonkey) and your code works for that too! Thanks.

Comment: Here on a windows computer, require seems to not be available?

Comment: @Roelant Are you using jupyter notebook?, This question is not about windows.